# View extents (scale to fit render window)

Tags: python, rendering

I'm trying to build an automatic renderer using Python, loading lots of OBJ files one-by-one and rendering the results.

I can load the files no problem, but because they are different sizes, I need to either:
1. Change the objects to the same size, or
2. Move the camera so the object fits

I can't seem to get either option to work!

Thus far, the best option seems perhaps to use `bpy.ops.object.dimensions` and then scale, but I can't seem to get the x/y/z dimensions out of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dimensions` is a property of `object` so you access it with `object.dimensions` not as a call to an operator. As a list of 3 values you can get the largest one with `max(object.dimensions)`, or you can look at each value with `object.dimensions.x`

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

maxDimension = 5.0

scaleFactor = maxDimension / max(obj.dimensions)

obj.scale = (scaleFactor,scaleFactor,scaleFactor)
```

This assumes you are starting with a scale of 1.0. If not then you may want to use `bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)` before starting.

Comment: It doesn't take the camera settings and distance to camera into account. If it's supposed to fit all objects into camera view, it will take quite some more effort. Operators like `bpy.ops.view3d.view_all()` fit the objects into viewport, but not camera view :(

Comment: Thanks - this is essentially what I've had but when I try to use `max` I get the error `TypeError: 'BPyOpsSubModOp' object is not iterable`, and when I try to access the component `x` I get the error `AttributeError: 'BPyOpsSubModOp' object has no attribute 'x'`.

Comment: You don't access object data through operators - that is don't use `bpy.ops.object` in front of `dimensions`. Once you import and the imported model is selected `bpy.context.active_object.dimensions` will be the dimensions of the active object. If the object isn't selected it may be easier to access it by name - `bpy.data.objects['new import'].dimensions`.

Comment: Thanks! I still really don't understand the difference between `ops`, `context`, and `data` but your suggestion using the named object worked the trick!

Comment: I thought I'd clarify that [as a question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9353/935)