# What is the difference between items listed in bpy.ops bpy.data and bpy.context

Tags: python

When accessing items in a python script somethings are prefixed with `bpy.data` some with `bpy.context` and others with `bpy.ops`

What is the difference between these prefixes?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Short Version

- `bpy.data` - all data in your blend file.
- `bpy.context` - data in the current active view.
- `bpy.ops` - tools which typically operate on `bpy.context`

---

### Longer Explanation

### `bpy.data`

gives you access to all data in the blend file, every object, material, compositing node etc. in every scene (also the scenes themselves) can be accessed through `bpy.data`.

Generally, you would either loop over all datablocks, or get a specific item by name.

### `bpy.context`

is context sensitive, it depends on the area your mouse is over, the selections you make and so on. It lists only a subset of `data` such as the current scene, the active object etc. This is an easy way to have a script work on whatever object is selected rather than having to know its name beforehand (`bpy.context.active_object` refers to the active object, or is `None` if there is no active object, `bpy.context.selected_objects` is a list of the selected objects).

### `bpy.ops`

is where you can access tools (operators) organized in categories, e.g. `bpy.ops.object.select_all()` (`object` is the category for object-related operations, together with `select_all` it is the operator name and `()` calls it). These perform the actions typically accessed in the user interface, referenced by menu items and key shortcuts. When you search using F3, you are seeing a list of all operators, which are available in the current context.

These three prefixes are the most common but there are others. `bpy.types` contains all the types or "classes" used within Blender. You will also use `bpy.utils` if you write an addon (mainly to register and unregister classes derived from bpy.types, e.g., to create own operators, menus, panels...). There are also some other modules available that aren't prefixed with `bpy` such as `mathutils` and `bmesh`.

For a list of all items available in Python you should look at [Blenders Python API documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/).