# Find and delete hidden objects

Tags: python, scripting, viewlayers

I made a small script that is supposed to select objects that have a material with an Image Texture.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
bpy.context.view_layer.objects

#first make sure everything is unselected
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.select_set(False)

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if ob.type == "MESH": #select only meshes
        for mat_slot in ob.material_slots:
            # if mat_slot.material:
            if mat_slot.material.node_tree:
                # print("material:" + str(mat_slot.material.name))                
                for x in mat_slot.material.node_tree.nodes:
                    if x.type=='TEX_IMAGE':
                        ob.select_set(True) #select if object has texture
```

When running the script for a particular scene it gives me the following error:

> `RuntimeError: Error: Object 'pape01t.002' can't be selected because it is not in View Layer 'ViewLayer'!`

After some digging I found the objects in current file collection

[image]

There is no option to turn them on (visible) so

1. How come these objects are in the current file collection but not visible in the actual object list [view layer] or [scene collection]?
2. How would I be able to ignore such objects or even better, find these hidden objects and delete them by script?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `bpy.data.objects`, use `bpy.context.scene.objects` to make sure you only loop through the objects that are currently in your active scene. The difference between these is explained [in this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9353/what-is-the-difference-between-items-listed-in-bpy-ops-bpy-data-and-bpy-context)

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    o.select_set(False)
    if o.type != "MESH":
        continue
    for mat_slot in o.material_slots:
        for x in mat_slot.material.node_tree.nodes:
            if x.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                o.select_set(True)
```

If you go under *Orphan Data* (broken heart symbol) under the *Outliner*, you will notice that there is a shield icon next to *Collection* which means there is a *Fake User* referencing all the data blocks within this collection that is why it didn't get removed when you did a *File > Clean Up*. Just click that *Fake User* icon to remove the fake user and then when doing a *File > Clean* Up it will remove these data blocks as well.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for the elaborate reply. The script works perfect. First time I see 'continue' used so ill look that up. As for unused data blocks. In my case I can only remove it with [Unused Local Data Blocks] and not [Unused Data Blocks]. In fact multiple times. First it removes the data from Collections and moves it into a Objects tab, after that I click again and it removes only 2. So I have to click the button multiple times before it gets removed. I assume that is not normal?

Comment: @JeeperCreeper continue can help reduce [excessive nesting of code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/626403/How-and-Why-to-Avoid-Excessive-Nesting). thats odd coz i did Unused Data Blocks and Recursive Unused Data Blocks and it was clean.